# bash: get content between a pair of XML tags and store them separately into multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a .xml file that looks like this,

Another thousand lines below this

```
<note>------------------------------------------+
<to>Tove</to>                                   |
<from>Jani</from>                               |
<heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 1.xml
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
</note>-----------------------------------------+
<note>------------------------------------------+
<to>Tove</to>                                   |
<from>Jani</from>                               |
<heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 2.xml
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
</note>-----------------------------------------+
<note>------------------------------------------+
<to>Tove</to>                                   |
<from>Jani</from>                               |
<heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 3.xml
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
</note>-----------------------------------------+
```

Here I'm trying to separate the data from  to  and move the data to multiple files

I tried the below code but it is getting the 1st part I'm unable to move the 2nd and 3rd part etc.

```
 sed -En 'H;$!d
        g;s/.*[\n](.*<note>.*\n.*<note>[^\n]*).*/\1/p
        ' sample.xml > 1.xml
```

Please help me to crack this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use an XML parser, or a language that has an XML library. `sed` is not appropriate.

Comment: To do this right, you'd need to recognize `<!--` as the start of a comment, and `-->` as the end of a comment; recognize a `<![CDATA[[` as meaning that everything until the next `]]>` is literal data, even if it looks like `</body>` or another tag; recognize an `xmlns="http://example.com/"` as meaning that a tag that looks like `<body>` under its position in the hierarchy is actually `{http://example.com}body`... and otherwise to recognize the myriad of other rules that apply to a compliant XML parser. This is not a job that `sed` is capable of doing correctly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Supports any structure / diff. no. of lines:

```
[gigauser@loriServer giga]$ cat big.xml
<note>------------------------------------------+
<to>Tove</to>                                   |
<from>Jani</from>                               |
<heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 1.xml
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
</note>-----------------------------------------+
<note>------------------------------------------+
<to>Tove</to>                                   |
<from>Jani</from>                               |
<heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 2.xml
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
</note>-----------------------------------------+
<note>------------------------------------------+
<to>Tove</to>                                   |
<from>Jani</from>                               |
<heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 3.xml
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
</note>-----------------------------------------+
[gigauser@loriServer giga]$ cat -n big.xml | sed "s/[ \t][ \t]*/ /g;s/^ //;s/ /:/"|egrep ":<note>|:<\/note>"|cut -d':' -f1 > lines.txt; c=1; while read lfrom; read lto; do sed -n "${lfrom},${lto}p" big.xml > ${c}.xml; ((c++)); done < lines.txt
[gigauser@loriServer giga]$
[gigauser@loriServer giga]$ ls -1 [1-9]*.xml
1.xml
2.xml
3.xml
[gigauser@loriServer giga]$
[gigauser@loriServer giga]$ cat -n 1.xml
     1  <note>------------------------------------------+
     2  <to>Tove</to>                                   |
     3  <from>Jani</from>                               |
     4  <heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 1.xml
     5  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
     6  </note>-----------------------------------------+
[gigauser@loriServer giga]$
[gigauser@loriServer giga]$ cat 2.xml
<note>------------------------------------------+
<to>Tove</to>                                   |
<from>Jani</from>                               |
<heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 2.xml
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
</note>-----------------------------------------+
[gigauser@loriServer giga]$
[gigauser@loriServer giga]$ cat 3.xml; rm lines.xml
<note>------------------------------------------+
<to>Tove</to>                                   |
<from>Jani</from>                               |
<heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 3.xml
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
</note>-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: sed is not a XML/HTML parser

Comment: I agree Gilles. But in a given "context" the above does solve the issue but I like your solution better. Up-voting it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex, nor sed but a proper XML/HTML parser and a powerful [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query :

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    xmllint  --xpath "//note[$i]" file > $i.xml
done
```

#### theory :

According to the compiling theory, HTML can't be parsed using regex based on [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Due to hierarchical construction of HTML you need to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) and manipulate [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) grammar using tool like [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

#### realLife©®™ everyday tool in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

You can use one of the following :

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) often installed by default with `libxml2`, xpath1 (check [my wrapper](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/xmllint) to have newlines delimited output

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) can edit, select, transform... Not installed by default, xpath1

[xpath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) installed via perl's module XML::XPath, xpath1

[xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) xpath3

[saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) my own project, wrapper over @Michael Kay's Saxon-HE Java library, xpath3

#### or you can use high level languages and proper libs, I think of :

[python](/questions/tagged/python)'s [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) (`from lxml import etree`)

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod), [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath), [`XML::Twig::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [nokogiri](/questions/tagged/nokogiri), [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-NokogiriXpath.rb.html)

[php](/questions/tagged/php) `DOMXpath`, [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-DOMXpath.php.html)

---

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Add `ruby` with nokogiri.

Comment: @dawg: this is DONE  :)

Comment: This is better solution but now I'm curious what value goes for `for` loop condition actually to support when # of lines are not same?

Comment: @Arun Dunno what you mean

Comment: @Gilles I meant, why `1..3` in the for loop, we don't know that if the structure inside the XML is not same per `<node>` header, right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (this solution assumes, you have data in every 6 lines):

```
c=1; while read l1 && read l2 && read l3 && read l4 && read l5 && read l6; do echo -e "$l1\n$l2\n$l3\n$l4\n$l5\n$l6\n" > ${c}.xml; ((c++)); done < big.xml; echo; find . | grep "[1-9]*.xml$"; echo; grep . [1-9]*.xml

./3.xml
./2.xml
./1.xml

1.xml:<note>------------------------------------------+
1.xml:<to>Tove</to>                                   |
1.xml:<from>Jani</from>                               |
1.xml:<heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 1.xml
1.xml:<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
1.xml:</note>-----------------------------------------+
2.xml:<note>------------------------------------------+
2.xml:<to>Tove</to>                                   |
2.xml:<from>Jani</from>                               |
2.xml:<heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 2.xml
2.xml:<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
2.xml:</note>-----------------------------------------+
3.xml:<note>------------------------------------------+
3.xml:<to>Tove</to>                                   |
3.xml:<from>Jani</from>                               |
3.xml:<heading>Reminder</heading>                     |--> To 3.xml
3.xml:<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>      |
3.xml:</note>-----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this without a proper parser in general. Since the example is already an invalid xml file, perhaps you can just separate the `<note> ... </note>` blocks.

If the file has that structure you can use this `awk` to separate out `<note> ... </note>` blocks and write to `1.xml, 2.xml...`:

```
awk '/^<note>/ {f=1;  s=$0 ORS; next}
     /^<\/note>/ {s=s $0 ORS; print s >++i ".xml"; f=0; next}
     f {s=s $0 ORS}' file.xml
```

That will not support any form of nesting of `<note> ... </note>` blocks. This or regex in general is a fragile approach to xml.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my more efficient solution, only reading the file once:

```
#!/bin/bash
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
i=0
while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" == '<note>' ]]
    then
        ((i++))
    fi
    echo "$line" >> note-$i.xml
done
IFS=$OIFS
```

Invocation:

```
./notes-xml.sh < notes.xml
```

(Deleted old one.)

Comment: Would you want to be the person tasked with supporting an API client/customer with production code based on this pattern? If your answer gets used -- and I'd hope you wouldn't provide if you didn't *want* it to be used -- then *someone* will be. (I've been the person to whom the support ticket got escalated when an API implementation change resulted in semantically-equivalent documents that broke a customer's hand-built parser; it's not any fun).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The solution was terrible inefficient. When the API changes, it is luck, if your automatic generated solution still works. The error is in the assumption, that the changes are semantically equivalent in respect to your tool. In reality, they often aren't. If building parsers with XML-tools would be such a fun, the support ticket should have been easy to fix for you - shouldn't it? Nonetheless, I was too unhappy with a program, reading the same file over and over again, and made a complete rewriting, but which still doesn't use the XMLfoo.

Comment: here's the thing -- as someone who has an API, the support ticket you get is something like "your API used to put one field per line, now it puts all the fields in a record on the same line, it's broken, change it back" -- or, for a change that just adds a new field, "your API used to create 6 lines per record, now it's 7, you need to rev the version when you make breaking changes", or such. Which is to say, it's not just the people writing code based on bad assumptions who get support tickets -- anyone whose customers/clients/consumers write bad code is in the firing line.

Comment: When you put answers like this out into the world, you're increasing the chance it'll be one of *my* customers who's doing this kind of innately-broken practice, and that I'll need to deal with the support tickets stemming from same. (Likewise, that it'll be one of your customers as well).

Comment: Come on - how long does it take to rewrite a 4-liner from scratch? The problem is, to interpolate an API from a one-times job. We don't know whether the problem will reappear and how the source of the file changes in the future. It's just speculation. XML-files can have multiple children (<to> could be repeated, for example) and your XML-tool might reorder them, because semantically it is equivalent. But it might not be for the customer. This so called xml-file doesn't even have a xml-header.

Comment: "How long does it take to rewrite a 4-liner from scratch?" -- for you or me, no time at all. For someone who's using this answer because they don't have any other ideas, that's a different matter -- and if the customer who's calling you to complain about a semantically-insignificant API change lets you see/rewrite/fix/do anything to their own internal proprietary client code, you live in a different world than I do. (BTW, I think you meant `IFS=$'\n'`, not `IFS=\n`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Solutions or tips I present are suggestions, what to try out. They aren't meant to be foolproof, nor to work under any condition. The site is for professionals and enthusiasts, so everybody has to know, that he has to inform about the suggestions being made. Not every posting can be an tutorial for experts and noobs meanwhile.  This question has currently a view impact of 42 views - I don't know whether you and me where counted each 5 times or whether it is unique viewers. So don't exaggerate the damage this has on your health and don't think every user here is stupid and stays…

Comment: …stupid, just to harm you. Get rid of your anger where you picked it up.

Comment: I picked it up at an old job where I got a bunch of the type of support tickets described above -- which is to say, what you're calling anger, someone else might call "experience".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: First, thanks for the IFS-advice. While I tested my original suggestion and it worked flawlessly, I don't understand why, and echoing the $IFS looks fishy, so I go with your advice in that regard. However - blindly adopting some somehow related answer to ones questions is never a good idea and you can't sanitize against abuse, lousy implementation, lazyness in research and testing. And no, I don't want any of my answers being just used in production - remember this is not a `rent a coder for free`-service. Test, try, compare, improve. I wouldn't use blindly some code I find.